# using wildcard in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|url                                        |
+-------------------------------------------+
|/v3/references/genders                     |
|/en/job/restaurant-manager-6619735/panels  |
|/en/job-search/dealer-coordinator-jobs/    |
|/en/job/engineer-3034030/panels            |
|/en/job/business-analyst-5385899           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to get the count for each url that contains 'job'. I tried this but I got empty result.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
spark.sql("select url, count(url) from table where url like 'job'").show()
```

What is wrong with that sql?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
spark.sql("select url, count(url) from table where url like '%job%' GROUP BY url").show()
```